# Dotnet core integration test fixture causing a json parsing error

Tags: .net-core, integration-testing, fixtures

So I am building a template API project and am currently working on adding in some integration tests.

At the moment, when I run my test, for some reason it returns a JSON parsing error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered
>   while parsing value: A. Path '', line 0, position 0.

This looks like it's an issue with my endpoint, but it works fine when just running localhost with a normal startup routine, so I think it's because I can't get my fixture just right. especilaly because, when i try another fixture (listed below) it doesn't give me an error anymore and just hangs.

The test itself can be found [here](https://github.com/pdevito3/foundation.api/blob/integration-tests/Foundation.Api.Tests/IntegrationTests/GetValueToReplaceIntegrationTests.cs).

```cs
namespace Foundation.Api.Tests.IntegrationTests
{
    using FluentAssertions;
    using Foundation.Api.Data;
    using Foundation.Api.Models;
    using Foundation.Api.Tests.Fakes;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xunit;

    public class GetValueToReplaceIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        public GetValueToReplaceIntegrationTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetValueToReplaces_ReturnsSuccessCodeAndResourceWithAccurateFields()
        {
            var fakeValueToReplaceOne = new FakeValueToReplace { }.Generate();
            var fakeValueToReplaceTwo = new FakeValueToReplace { }.Generate();

            var appFactory = _factory;
            using (var scope = appFactory.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ValueToReplaceDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                context.ValueToReplaces.RemoveRange(context.ValueToReplaces);
                context.ValueToReplaces.AddRange(fakeValueToReplaceOne, fakeValueToReplaceTwo);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var client = appFactory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            });

            var result = await client.GetAsync($"api/v1/ValueToReplaceLowers")
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            var responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ValueToReplaceDto>>(responseContent);

            // Assert
            result.StatusCode.Should().Be(200);
            response.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(fakeValueToReplaceOne);
            response.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(fakeValueToReplaceTwo);
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

The fixture can be found [here](https://github.com/pdevito3/foundation.api/blob/integration-tests/Foundation.Api.Tests/CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs).

```cs
namespace Foundation.Api.Tests
{
    using Foundation.Api.Data;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Remove the app's ValueToReplaceDbContext registration.
                var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(DbContextOptions<ValueToReplaceDbContext>));

                if (descriptor != null)
                {
                    services.Remove(descriptor);
                }

                // Add ValueToReplaceDbContext using an in-memory database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<ValueToReplaceDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestingDb");
                });

                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
                // context (ValueToReplaceDbContext).
                using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ValueToReplaceDbContext>();

                    // Ensure the database is created.
                    db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    try
                    {
                        db.RemoveRange(db.ValueToReplaces);
                        // Seed the database with test data.
                        //Utilities.InitializeDbForTests(db);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried a fixture [like so](https://gist.github.com/pdevito3/192072c5b197c531337383aadb37af70) inspired by [this one](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders/blob/2bdd29b8b4953be9fa06d60faf67e13d542a120e/Tests/WebUI.IntegrationTests/Common/CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs) which just times out.

```cs
namespace Foundation.Api.Tests
{
    using Foundation.Api.Data;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Create a new service provider.
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                // Add a database context using an in-memory 
                // database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<ValueToReplaceDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                });

                services.AddScoped(provider => provider.GetService<ValueToReplaceDbContext>());

                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
                using var scope = sp.CreateScope();
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var context = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ValueToReplaceDbContext>();

                // Ensure the database is created.
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                try
                {
                    // Seed the database with test data.
                    //Utilities.InitializeDbForTests(context);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the " +
                    //                    $"database with test messages. Error: {ex.Message}");
                }
            })
                .UseEnvironment("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

The repo can be found [here](https://github.com/pdevito3/foundation.api).

Comment: Could you please post a reproducible sample here, instead of posting a links to different files and repos?

Comment: sure thing. done!